# trying to send mail using swift mailer, gmail smtp, php

Tags: php, smtp, swiftmailer

Here is my code:

```
<?php
require_once 'Swift/lib/swift_required.php';

$transport = Swift_SmtpTransport::newInstance('smtp.gmail.com', 465)
  ->setUsername('me@ff.com')
  ->setPassword('pass');

$mailer = Swift_Mailer::newInstance($transport);
$message = Swift_Message::newInstance('Wonderful Subject')
  ->setFrom(array('me@ff.com' => 'MY NAME'))
  ->setTo(array('you@ss.com' => 'YOU'))
  ->setBody('This is the text of the mail send by Swift using SMTP transport.');
//$attachment = Swift_Attachment::newInstance(file_get_contents('path/logo.png'), 'logo.png');  
//$message->attach($attachment);
$numSent = $mailer->send($message);
printf("Sent %d messages\n", $numSent);
?>
```

AFter RUNNING GOT THIS ERROR...

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Swift_TransportException' with message 'Expected response code 220 but got code "", with message ""' in /home/sitenyou/public_html/Swift/lib/classes/Swift/Transport/AbstractSmtpTransport.php:406

```
Stack trace: 
#0 /home/sitenyou/public_html/Swift/lib/classes/Swift/Transport/AbstractSmtpTransport.php(299): Swift_Transport_AbstractSmtpTransport->_assertResponseCode('', Array) 
#1 /home/sitenyou/public_html/Swift/lib/classes/Swift/Transport/AbstractSmtpTransport.php(107): Swift_Transport_AbstractSmtpTransport->_readGreeting() 
#2 /home/sitenyou/public_html/Swift/lib/classes/Swift/Mailer.php(74): Swift_Transport_AbstractSmtpTransport->start() 
#3 /home/sitenyou/public_html/sgmail.php(16): Swift_Mailer->send(Object(Swift_Message)) 
#4 {main} thrown in /home/sitenyou/public_html/Swift/lib/classes/Swift/Transport/AbstractSmtpTransport.php on line 406
```

Comment: Really strange is one thing. When I try to do the same thing in Eclipse, the autocomplete doesn't show `setUsername` and `setPassword` methods. I wonder are they possible or is Eclipse buggy with, that feature.

Comment: @Eugene As far as I can tell, the magic `__call()` method handles those functions, so the lack of autocomplete is normal (no `@method` phpdoc either).

Comment: Please refer the Tutorial, It is showing how to use Shiftmailer http://sgeek.org/send-email-attachment-using-swiftmailer-symfony/

Answer (score 53, accepted):

GMail's SMTP requires encryption. Use:

```
Swift_SmtpTransport::newInstance('smtp.gmail.com', 465, "ssl");
```

Answer (score 8):

there is missing the ssl parameter, it should be something like that

```
Swift_SmtpTransport::newInstance('smtp.gmail.com', 465, "ssl")
```

Tested and work fine

Comment: this is identical as the selected answer

Answer (score 3):

Swift SmtpTransport - Code (send a email)

The SMTP of GMAIL is: smtp.googlemail.com

The Full Code:

```
<?php
$pEmailGmail = 'xxxx@gmail.com';
$pPasswordGmail = '********';
$pFromName = 'MundialSYS.com'; //display name

$pTo = 'xxxxxx@xxxx.xxx'; //destination email
$pSubjetc = "Hello MundialSYS"; //the subjetc 
$pBody = '<html><body><p>Hello MundialSYS</p></html></body>'; //body html

$transport = Swift_SmtpTransport::newInstance('smtp.googlemail.com', 465, 'ssl')
            ->setUsername($pEmailGmail)
            ->setPassword($pPasswordGmail);

$mMailer = Swift_Mailer::newInstance($transport);

$mEmail = Swift_Message::newInstance();
$mEmail->setSubject($pSubjetc);
$mEmail->setTo($pTo);
$mEmail->setFrom(array($pEmailGmail => $pFromName));
$mEmail->setBody($pBody, 'text/html'); //body html

if($mMailer->send($mEmail) == 1){
    echo 'send ok';
}
else {
    echo 'send error';
}
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

I cannot be sure, but I think that Gmail's port is 587 using TLS, which is not SSL, but a newer version of it. You should check into that, because I think you are placing the wrong construction code.

Best of luck!

Answer (score 2):

I have managed to get this working without the SSL, here is how:

```
$transport = Swift_SmtpTransport::newInstance('tls://smtp.gmail.com', 465)
            ->setUsername('contact@columbussoft.com')
            ->setPassword('password');
$mailer = Swift_Mailer::newInstance($transport);

$message = Swift_Message::newInstance($subject)
            ->setFrom(array($emailTo=>$name))
            ->setTo(array($emailTo=>'Neo Nosrati'))
            ->addPart($body,'text/plain')
            ->setReturnPath('other@columbussoft.com');
```

Comment: I don't know if my work's proxy blocks the other method of using SwiftMailer but this answer works for me so if people are having difficulty with the third parameter `'ssl'` option, try this instead. Thanks @Neo.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using the "Messages Swift Mailer" bundle in Laravel 3 and having the same issue. After some testing, in my case, the solution was to set the same email address that I used in the SMTP authentication on the "from" parameter.

I was trying to use a different address and that was triggering the **"swiftmailer expected response code 220 but got code with message"** error.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

I got same error before and i added "ssl" parameter in  Swift_SmtpTransport::newInstance('smtp.gmail.com', 465, "ssl") like osos said.

IT WORKS!! thanks..:D

this is my code:

```
<?php
require_once 'swift/lib/swift_required.php';

$transport = Swift_SmtpTransport::newInstance('smtp.gmail.com', 465, "ssl")
  ->setUsername('XXXXXXX@gmail.com')
  ->setPassword('XXXXXXX');

$mailer = Swift_Mailer::newInstance($transport);
$message = Swift_Message::newInstance('THIS IS THE SUBJECT')
  ->setFrom(array('XXXXXXX@gmail.com' => 'YOUR NAME'))
  ->setTo(array('XXXXXXX@gmail.com' => 'YOU'))
  ->setBody('This is the text of the mail send by Swift using SMTP transport.');
//$attachment = Swift_Attachment::newInstance(file_get_contents('path/logo.png'), 'logo.png');  
//$message->attach($attachment);
$numSent = $mailer->send($message);
printf("Sent %d messages\n", $numSent);
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

For google apps, in addition to setting to port 465 and ssl as recommended in the accepted answer, you may have to [enable allow less secure apps](https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps) setting, as per https://stackoverflow.com/a/25238515/947370

Answer (score 0):

Given the age of the question I have just recently had to go through this process so I would like to confirm for anyone still coming here that it is all still relavent ^^ but here is a full guide on how to enable 2-Step Verification, get your App Password and send an email.

```
composer require swiftmailer/swiftmailer
```

When using gmail as mentioned previously you need to have 2-Step Verification enabled on your Google Account and create an App Password.

[image: How to get to 2-Step Verification on your Google Account]

Click on the 9 dots > Security > 2-Step Verification > Get Started
Enter your mobile and then verify the device.

Once you have enabled it you need to go to 2-Step Verification and then scroll to the bottom and find App Passwords.

[image]

Create a new password and then use it in your code as below:

[image]

```
<?php
require $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/vendor/autoload.php';

$transport = (new Swift_SmtpTransport('smtp.gmail.com', 587, 'tls'))
          ->setUsername('youremail@address.com')
          ->setPassword('yourapppassword');
$message_text = "Hello User,\n\This is the body of your email message";
$message = (new Swift_Message('Your Email Subject'))
->setFrom(['youremail@address.com' => 'Your From Name'])
->setBody($message_text);
$mailer = new Swift_Mailer($transport);
$message->setTo('whereyouwantto@email.com');
$result = $mailer->send($message);
?>
```