# Alternative ways for sending mail on shared hosting with bad IP

Tags: php, email, smtp, gmail, shared-hosting

What are alternative ways if the IP address of your shared hosting has a "bad reputation"? Gmail blocks the mail, says mails from this IP address are likely to be SPAM.

Are there workarounds other than switching to virtual or dedicated server? Is there any way to send mails via a third party, different IP? Like a gmail smtp? How would this work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's more likely to work as you are sending through their SMTP.

I would recommend [PHPMailer](http://code.google.com/a/apache-extras.org/p/phpmailer/).

You should also know that GMail has limitations on emails sent, as it can block your host if your trying to send too much emails.

Comment: never knew :), I made some tests a few years ago and made a script wrong and Google banned me after 30 mails. Those mails where sent within 5 seconds.

Comment: oh... I see. But I don't get what is so different with PHPMailer? It just looks like a nice and easy way to send mails - why should it be different?

Comment: It's not, you can use what framework you want. I use what I've wrote few years ago and still works, and connects threw `SSL` and does my work, PHPMailer is easier to use. Why reinvent the wheel?

Comment: yeah, true! no, sorry... I meant they do not provide their smtp, do they? so I'll have to use gmail smtp or sth again? sorry, I just did not get it...

Comment: yes, you have to use a SMTP, like Google. No matter what script you will eventually use, you need to have an SMTP server.

Comment: OK, I see, thank you! Just because you wrote that Google banned you after 30 mails... this would not happen using PHPMailer?

Comment: I do believe it will ban/block your scripts if you are using anything, it doesn't matter what script you use, you should not send too may emails/1 second [Bulk GMAIL](https://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?hl=en&ctx=rosetta&answer=81126&rd=1)

Comment: oh... sorry, did not see the link! this is very helpful, thx!! :)

Comment: that is not a problem, they should be **newsletters** like .. or **spam** like. They can be a few thousands a day if you are not spamming :)

Answer (score 2):

Did you tried to send a Message over another SMTP Server?

I would try Swiftmailer:  http://swiftmailer.org/docs/sending.html

In example: [trying to send mail using swift mailer, gmail smtp, php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3536836/trying-to-send-mail-using-swift-mailer-gmail-smtp-php)