# Iam trying send email with php mailer and found this error

Tags: phpmailer

```
2017-09-19 08:09:53 SMTP ERROR: Failed to connect to server: (0)
SMTP connect() failed. 

https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting
```

Message could not be sent.Mailer Error: SMTP connect() failed.

```
https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting.
```

The above is the error I got.

Comment: Your configuration might be wrong. [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36351817/phpmailer-smtp-error-failed-to-connect-to-server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36351817/phpmailer-smtp-error-failed-to-connect-to-server)

Comment: People might need more information here. Maybe the configuration you are using

Comment: port = 465 , $mail->isHTML(true) in php.ini i configured everything and uncommented what all needed.

Comment: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in C:\xampp\htdocs\gautam\vendor\phpmailer\phpmailer\src\SMTP.php on line 1115. This is error iam getting now and my timeout is set to 300.

Answer (score 1):

The error says you are trying to connect to a server and the connection to the network socket is failing.  In order you should check:

1. Are you connecting to the right server?
2. Is it running an SMTP server?
3. Is there a firewall that is configured to reject your connection request on the server?
4. Is there a firewall that is rejecting your connection request in between you and the server?

Comment: Go through the whole checklist.

Comment: ya..i pressed allow couple of times and it is not coming now... How can i solve the issue