# heroku smtplib need to log into browser

Tags: python-3.x, heroku, smtp, gmail

I have pushed a bot onto heroku with feedback capability (email) but i need to log into web browser before gmail will allow me to use it. Any way round this?

> smtplib.SMTPAuthenticationError: (534, b'5.7.14  /**Please log in via your web browser and\n5.7.14 then try again**.\n5.7.14  Learn more at\n5.7.14  https://support.google.com/mail/answer/78754 d9sm5410600qte.0 - gsmtp')

Error from logs

Comment: did you find the answer?

Comment: @Juan, I didn't find a solution. I just saw https://stackoverflow.com/q/20337040/4180176 which may have a solution in it though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The linked question is closed so I'll post here what worked for me.

I has to allow less secure apps on my google account as previously described. Then on Google, I has to create a specific password for the Heroku app as described here https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/185833?authuser=2