# Unable to send mails in Python

Tags: python

I am new to python. I am trying to send mails using the following Python code
and I am using a code editor Jupyter. I have enabled IMAP in my gmail account and have turned on the access for less secured app. The code editor i am using is unable to compile the line

```
server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
```

Can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong?

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import smtplib
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart  
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
fromaddr = 'abc@gmail.com' 
toaddr = 'abc@gmail.com' 
msg = MIMEMultipart()
msg['From'] = fromaddr
msg['To'] = toaddr
msg['Subject'] = 'SUBJECT OF THE MAIL'
body = 'YOUR MESSAGE HERE'
msg.attach(MIMEText(body, 'plain'))

server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
server.ehlo()
server.starttls()
server.login(fromaddr, 'YOUR PASSWORD')
text = msg.as_string()
server.sendmail(fromaddr, toaddr, text)
server.quit()
```

Comment: What do you mean *"unable to compile"* - do you see an error message? What happens? Give a [mcve].

Comment: Exactly what error message are you getting?  Could you add that information to your question?

Comment: Hi, following is the error
File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/smtplib.py", line 622, in login
    raise SMTPAuthenticationError(code, resp)
smtplib.SMTPAuthenticationError: (534, '5.7.14 <https://accounts.google.com/signin/continue?sarp=1&scc=1&plt=AKgnsbt0\n5.7.14 pdRjQcQoqo8rS20uCoVPcYkisf5HYwlZzz8BIM7qwtBSdEVAXlkA1eWx4najAuvP3PJqPE\n5.7.14 4lsXzOkGDu5rkLNJKHN4ihC6ZeNb9DSloSdAPvvBRoRabCCRuGVa11d3aS9CJqQKTHO_rC\n5.7.14 gUw7lSEYWHIJuY9P7lE9oKVP_j5LNHr9MxajFLKulBanSg57BfaaT0Ze_5hjrJfOChXyxu\n5.7.14 2VwndccEZCbxPcok1peTP3jLXRocA> Please log in via your web browser and\n5.7.14

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Gmail SMTP debug: error "please log in via your web browser"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20337040/gmail-smtp-debug-error-please-log-in-via-your-web-browser)