# sending email from django app doesnt work from server

Tags: django

I have an app that sends out an email when an object is create,
this is the code for sending email:

```
from django.core.mail import send_mail    
send_mail("New entryis added", "Hi a new entry is added", "myemail@gmail.com", [c.email for c in CustomUser.objects.all()], fail_silently=False)
```

and this is my setting:

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'myemail'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'password'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
```

I also made sure that my "Less secure app access" is on in google security setting.
So with all thses I am able to send email with no issue in local server.
However when I push the code to digital ocean droplet linux server, it throws some errors:

```
SMTPAuthenticationError at /a/b/c/add/

(534, b'5.7.14 <https://accounts.google.com/signin/continue?sarp=1&scc=1&plt=AKgnsbu\n5.7.14 VVGrAjSoYzu_W9fGpWsq5B3qMs04qWLzeqnxkFdrMaeVJumRRljQzXEyYpA9xt1MSYaii\n5.7.14 iyVCj2qaXbQzY5Tvc3mux9qViJSKE5yOozpCzao_qU0FhjYGX8IZ1xgd9PUep41I>\n5.7.14 Please log in via your web browser and then try again.\n5.7.14  Learn more at\n5.7.14  https://support.google.com/mail/answer/78754 g9sm2079574pgj.89 - gsmtp')

Exception Type:     SMTPAuthenticationError
```

I apreciate if someone can shed some light on what is the issue,
Thanks,

Comment: You've shown how you're trying to call send_mail() function.. please include send_mail() definition as well..

Comment: @Ronnie Thats the standard send mail method from django.core.mail. The definition for it is in the Django docs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

following this post:

[Getting error while sending email through Gmail SMTP - "Please log in via your web browser and then try again. 534-5.7.14"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20337040/getting-error-while-sending-email-through-gmail-smtp-please-log-in-via-your-w)

Clicking on this resolved the issue:

https://accounts.google.com/b/0/DisplayUnlockCaptcha

Answer (score 0):

One thing I have used to fix this is to put the TLS variable first. Put this above all the other settings.

`EMAIL_USE_TLS = True`

Try this to help diagnose it. You can send emails from the Django shell, so ssh into your server and try this.

```
>>> from django.core.mail import send_mail
>>> send_mail('test email', 'hello world', 'myemail@gmail.com', ['your@email.com'])
```

Test to see if this is more informative.