# Error in sending mail via STMP in aws elasticbeanstalk

Tags: python, django, email, smtp, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am unable to resolve this error. I am running django. It works properly on my local, but I have deployed the code to aws elasticbeanstalk where it throws the below error.

Also my smtp configuration is something like this.

I have also tried to ALLOW low secure apps in Google settings.

But nothing seems to work.

```
# SMTP configuration
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'email@gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'password'
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
```

Environment:

```
Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://odm-masala-app-env.eba-ijhfppue.us-west-2.elasticbeanstalk.com/accounts/register/

Django Version: 3.1
Python Version: 3.7.10

Installed Applications:

['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'category',
 'accounts',
 'store',
 'carts',
 'orders',
 'admin_honeypot',
 'storages']

Installed Middleware:

['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
 'django_session_timeout.middleware.SessionTimeoutMiddleware']



Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/app/venv/staging-LQM1lest/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/var/app/venv/staging-LQM1lest/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 179, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/var/app/current/accounts/views.py", line 53, in register
    send_email.send()
  File "/var/app/venv/staging-LQM1lest/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/mail/message.py", line 284, in send
    return self.get_connection(fail_silently).send_messages([self])
  File "/var/app/venv/staging-LQM1lest/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/mail/backends/smtp.py", line 102, in send_messages
    new_conn_created = self.open()
  File "/var/app/venv/staging-LQM1lest/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/mail/backends/smtp.py", line 69, in open
    self.connection.login(self.username, self.password)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.7/smtplib.py", line 730, in login
    raise last_exception
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.7/smtplib.py", line 721, in login
    initial_response_ok=initial_response_ok)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.7/smtplib.py", line 642, in auth
    raise SMTPAuthenticationError(code, resp)

Exception Type: SMTPAuthenticationError at /accounts/register/
Exception Value: (534, b'5.7.14 <https://accounts.google.com/signin/continue?sarp=1&scc=1&plt=AKgnsbt\n5.7.14 JzmJlDR_KXwRjsGoeGbUwfJiFaseGdN7r4Tr5kVIBAWkZ_KxJtmoZ21tvxssaWR96lYr1\n5.7.14 1McFMOBeAoLgjKAhaZSf7Z0H7mCYUPyXbKlQ-CmDohYCNFK3GmWZG47EBOB2uOnH>\n5.7.14 Please log in via your web browser and then try again.\n5.7.14  Learn more at\n5.7.14  https://support.google.com/mail/answer/78754 63sm12202837pfz.119 - gsmtp')
```

Comment: Maybe this answer might help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25238515/15353043

Answer (score 0):

This is because gmail uses captcha verification, please try disabling it from below link.
[https://accounts.google.com/DisplayUnlockCaptcha](https://%20https://accounts.google.com/DisplayUnlockCaptcha)