# Symfony SwiftMailer - Expected response code 220 but got code "", with message ""

Tags: php, symfony, smtp, gmail, swiftmailer

I know this question has a bunch of answers like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3536836/trying-to-send-mail-using-swift-mailer-gmail-smtp-php) on SO already but none of the solutions seem to work for me.

I am trying to send an email from my Google Apps Domain. Emails are being sent most of the time but sometimes this exception gets thrown and the email doesn't get sent.

```
Uncaught PHP Exception Swift_TransportException: "Expected response code 220 but got code "", with message """ at C:\HostingSpaces\abc\domain.com\wwwroot\vendor\swiftmailer\swiftmailer\lib\classes\Swift\Transport\AbstractSmtpTransport.php line 383 {"exception":"[object] (Swift_TransportException(code: 0): Expected response code 220 but got code \"\", with message \"\" at C:\\HostingSpaces\\abc\\domain.com\\wwwroot\\vendor\\swiftmailer\\swiftmailer\\lib\\classes\\Swift\\Transport\\AbstractSmtpTransport.php:383)"} []
```

Yes, I use SSL, yes, I have given access to less secure apps and yes I use port 465. I have enabled spooling so that the app doesn't crash because the exception doesn't get caught.

My config.yml is below

```
swiftmailer:
    transport:  smtp
    host:       smtp.gmail.com
    username:   no-reply@googledomain.com
    password:   password
    port:       465
    encryption: ssl
    spool: { type: memory }
```

And my email class is below

```
public function send_new_order_email($entity) {
    try{
        $message = $this->getEmailObj("toaddress@gmail.com");
        $message->setBody(
                $this->renderView(
                    'APIBundle:Emails:ops_neworder.html.twig',
                    array('entity' => $entity)
                ),
                'text/html'
            )->setSubject('New Order : '.$entity->getId());

        $this->container->get('mailer')->send($message);
    }
    catch(Exception $e){}
}

private function getEmailObj($email){
    $message = \Swift_Message::newInstance()
            ->setFrom('no-reply@googledomain.com')
            ->setTo($email);
    return $message;
}
```

Do you have any suggestions to make this work?

Answer (score 0):

There is in Symfony with Swiftmailer an specialized configuration for Gmail, it handle the email communication forgetting the rest of the configuration. This work for me in many ocassions:

```
swiftmailer:
    transport: gmail
    username:  your_gmail_username
    password:  your_gmail_password
```

I hope this make sense for you

[You have more information here](https://symfony.com/doc/current/email/gmail.html)